# If a bipartite graph on vertices $V_1 \cup V_2$ has a Hamiltonian path, then $|V_1|- |V_2| \leq 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Suppose $G = (V,E)$ is a bipartite graph with partition $V = V_1  \cup  V_2$. Show that if $G$ has a Hamiltonian path, then $|V_1| - |V_2| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your bipartite $G$ has a Hamiltonian path, then that path must visit the vertices of $V_1$ and $V_2$ in an alternating fashion. So for $u_i \in V_1$ and $w_i \in V_2$ the path looks like one of
$$\begin{align}
  u_1 \to w_1 \to &\dotsb \to w_k \\
  u_1 \to w_1 \to &\dotsb \to u_k \\
  w_1 \to u_1 \to &\dotsb \to w_k \\
  w_1 \to u_1 \to &\dotsb \to u_k
\end{align}$$ 
Since each vertex of the graph is visited exactly once, in each case you can't have $|V_1|$ and $|V_2|$ differ by more than one.